# manipulate php array or object

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I've a problem with my php object.

explain:
I have this:

```
array (size=7)
'1stObject' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'from' => string '1168498' (length=7)
          'to' => string '0' (length=1)
          'inner' => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'from' => string '0' (length=1)
          'to' => string '2379217' (length=7)
          'inner' => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'from' => string '0' (length=1)
          'to' => string '0' (length=1)
          'inner' => string '249111' (length=6)
```

But my problem is I want this:

```
 array (size=7)
    '1stObject' => 
        array (size=3)
          'from' => string '1168498' (length=7)
          'to' => string '2379217' (length=7)
          'inner' => string '249111' (length=6)
```

How can I do this?

I tested with array_merge, and other array function, but nothing help me..

Anyone have a function or a solution for me?

Thank you !

Comment: What's your original data structure look like that created the array you have now?

Comment: So you only need the first child of `1stObject` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use `array_filter` and clear the unneeded. Sample: [**Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LmYf9I)

```
foreach($values as &$object) {
    $temp = array();
    foreach($object as $key => $value) {
        $value = array_filter($value); // clear zeroes
        $temp[key($value)] = current($value); // transfer
    }
    $object = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what is your actual array complete structure, this may help you

```
foreach($yourarray['1stObject'] as $subarray)
{
if($subarray['from']!=0)
$newarray['1stObject']['from'] = $subarray['from'];

if($subarray['to']!=0)
$newarray['1stObject']['to'] = $subarray['to'];

if($subarray['inner']!=0)
$newarray['1stObject']['inner'] = $subarray['inner'];
}

print_r($newarray);
```